# Not able to create a project in GCP by using a service account through API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service, accounts, gcp

### Description

I am facing an issue while attempting to create a project in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) using a service account through the API. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Initially, I manually created a project in which I set up a service account and assigned it the role of owner.
2. I ensured that the necessary APIs were enabled, including:

   - Cloud Resource Manager API
   - IAM Service Account Credentials API
   - Identity and Access Management (IAM) API
   - Service Management API
3. I utilized the following API endpoint to create a project:

```
POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v3/projects
{
    "parent": "organizations/{organizationID}",
    "projectId": "my-project",
    "displayName": "my-project"
}
```

However, despite these steps, I am encountering the following error: "The caller does not have permission."

## Additional Information:

- The service account has the role of owner.
- All required APIs are enabled.
- The API request includes the correct parameters.

## Error Message:

"The caller does not have permission."

## Expected Outcome:

I expect to successfully create a project using the provided API request and the service account with the owner role. However, I am consistently receiving the permission error mentioned above.

## Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

```
1. Verified that the service account has the necessary permissions.
2. Checked and ensured that all required APIs are enabled.
3. Reviewed the API request for any potential errors in parameters.
```

**help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!**